# Retrieve a List of Calls made Through Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio

For a call tracking application I'm developing, I want to maintain local database.

As it stands, the application searches for new records in Twilio and inserts them into my database every time it loads. This is very time consuming.

In order to avoid that runtime expense, is there a way I can use usage triggers in Twilio to automatically populate my database in real time? Or even just daily?

If not, how can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Twilio is already calling your servers (unless there's some way to use it without doing that, but I don't think there is), can't you implement logging there? For instance, before you feed back your greeting, pop in a logging routine to note that you've received a call?

I'm not sure if they offer any other sorts of APIs or callbacks, but I really don't see why anything like that would be necessary. It'd just tie up your servers with more requests at no additional gain. I was just going through their documentation and I don't see anything like this. I could be just totally glossing over it, but again it just seems redundant. The entire Twilio system is based effectively on event hooks, so having separate ones wouldn't serve much additional use.

On the other hand, if for some reason you have absolutely no access whatsoever to the code or people behind the code that serves TwiML back, unless someone else is seeing an event hook API, you might want to just set up a scheduled job on your server (or in Azure, or whatever you're using) to query Twilio daily, since I know you mentioned that that would be sufficient. You could also, of course, set it more frequently. But that really seems like a waste of resources and effort when they're already telling you everything about every call through the massive list of query parameters they pass with every request.